# material Slider tooltip color not changing com.google.android.material.slider.Slider

Tags: android, material-ui, slider, material-design

i'm using material Slider https://material.io/components/sliders/android https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/Slider

```
        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/range_seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stepSize="0.1"
        android:value="0.7"
        android:valueFrom="0.3"
        android:valueTo="1"
        app:labelStyle="@style/Tooltip"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView9"
        app:thumbColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:thumbRadius="8dp"
        app:trackColorActive="@color/colorAccent"
        app:trackColorInactive="#60478FE3" />
```

and my @style/Tooltip

```
    <style name="Tooltip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Tooltip">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

but my tooltip color remains unchanged [screenshot attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFsfD.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the Tooltip background color you have to use the `backgroundTint` property and to change the Tooltip text color you have to use a custom `android:textAppearance` style like in the below example:

```
<style name="Tooltip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Tooltip">
    <!--This is the Tooltip textAppearance -->
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Tooltip</item>
    <!--This is the Tooltip Background Color -->
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Tooltip" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Tooltip">
    <!--This is the Tooltip Text Color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

and you can use the above custom Tooltip Style like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
   app:labelStyle="@style/Tooltip"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Result:**

[image: tooltip_slider_color]

Comment: If you are using Material3 instead of MaterialComponents you then the textColor needs to be set in the "Tooltip" style itself.

`<style name="Tooltip" parent="Widget.Material3.Tooltip">`
`<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>`
`<item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>`
`</style>`